# Sort excel formula output?

Tags: excel

I have made an excel column with a formula. Now I would like to sort this column by number... Just using sort won't work, because it sorts the formula ( =if(; =abs( etc.) and not the numbers that I see.
Can somebody help me with this please?

Comment: is copying and pasting the values out of the question, if you do not wish to remove the formula perhaps use an extra column to paste the values into and hide it

Comment: Excel isn't supposed to sort formulas. It should sort the values. Can you post the data in the order in which it is sorted?

Comment: I agree with Cutter, what formula are you using?

Comment: I agree with Tom, this is how Excel sorts things like "Vlookup" for example, a 'Copy > Paste Special > Values' will fix this.

Comment: how can it possibly sort by formulas ?!? it's not like formula in 2nd row would point to 5th row and formula in 3rd row to 19th... it might be possible it is sorted as text and not as numbers, you should use `value(...)` if that is the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can sort Excel/LibreOffice cells using just formulas only.

1. My unsorted numbers ( or words ) are listed horizontally. e.g. B29 – G29 ( 6 numbers ). I choose 29 so that it wont be confused with the 1 used in RANK function :D
2. My sorted numbers shall be in cells J29-O29.
3. The formula for cell J29 is

> =IF(RANK($B29,$B29:$G29,1)=1,$B29,IF(RANK($C29,$B29:$G29,1)=1,$C29,IF(RANK($D29,$B29:$G29,1)=1,$D29,IF(RANK($E29,$B29:$G29,1)=1,$E29,IF(RANK($F29,$B29:$G29,1)=1,$F29,IF(RANK($G29,$B29:$G29,1)=1,$G29,$Q29))))))

1. The formula for cell K29 is … just convert all the `“=1″` into `“=2″`
2. The formula for the rest is `“=3″` for L29 and so on till `“=6″` for O29.
3. The `RANK` function will rank every cell in the range. There will not be any unranked.
4. The last part .. ,`IF(RANK($G29,$B29:$G29,1)=1,$G29,$Q29)`
   If there are more than one same number .. meaning there are more than one number of the same rank.. it would duplicated the previous number of the same rank.
5. To sort words, you need to first convert words into ASCII using the `CODE` function. The `RANK` function works only with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to take the output value from a formula field and then have them sorted in the following column?

If so try this:

```
 =large(b$1:b$5000,rows($a$1:a1))
 rows($x$1:x1) =1 dragged down becomes
 rows($x$1:x2) ie =2
```

It counts the number of rows in the range.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for sorting the numbers alone in a particular column you can try this:

```
=LARGE($B$1:$B$5000,COUNT(B1:B5000)
```

`=LARGE(ARRAY,K)` this will return the kth largest number in the given array
here `=COUNT(B1:B5000)` will return 7 which is the value of k.

Our final formula will look like
`=LARGE($B$1:$B$5000,5000)` which is the smallest number in the entire range.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> by selecting the range from b1:b5000 so that it will sort the numbers from b1:b5000.

Answer (score 0):

beware sorting lines using formula as index key.  Sort will use the proper formula value to sort the lines.  However, the formulas will remain unchanged and will be re-evaluated.

Example : 
on you line 2, colum B: =`VLOOKUP(E2,BW!A$2:D$93,3)`
- extend the formula to every lines below
- after the sort, line number 4 might appear first in the new list
- then line 1 columb B: =`VLOOKUP(E4,BW!A$2:D$93,3)`
- notice the E4 in the formula does not point E1 at you might expect.